# Change AWS windows machine

Tags: sql-server, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

Currently I have got an AWS EC2 windows server machine along with SQL Server Web Edition. 
In order to reduce costs, I want to get rid of SQL server web edition and put express edition on the same machine.

Can I do it? I was thinking of uninstalling web edition and then installing express edition on the same server. Will this suffice?

Any insights would be highly appreciated. 
P.S. I do not have support plan with AWS, and that is why I am writing here on Stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The price for the instance is **determined by the AMI that was used when launching the instance**. Even if you uninstall SQL Server, you will still be charged the same hourly charge.

You will need to **launch a new instance** with the desired version. You'll also need to migrate the data and any other software you have installed on the instance.

It's probably a good time to **consider using Amazon RDS**, which is a fully-managed database service that can keep the database separate from your other sofware.